# Delete Title and Icone in Homepage

Tags: homepage

[image]

Hi, my website im doing now is nurulsazlinprubsntakaful.com

i want to delete home ---> Home as per pic i attach.

i read its about breadcrumbs. i also use inspect function in web browser.i get code like this from some discussion in other forum. 
.title-box {
    display: none;
}

i put in additional css. still not solve.

im very new in wordpress. hope someone can help me...tq2.

other than that, i also awant to delete icon share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check your theme's settings, if breadcrumbs can be turned on/off. If not, the following CSS will hide breadcrumbs:

```
nav.breadcrumbs {
    display: none;
}
```

Put the above lines, into Customize -> Additional CSS, or into your theme's `style.css`.

To remove sharing buttons, use the following CSS:

```
div.share.js-share {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: thank you. both code works perfectly. but first code there is typo. maybe u can edit a bit. so that other people can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I helped you hide the header in another question.  Just curious how did you come up with .title-box?  What you want to do is hit F12 and get the class or ID of the outer most element you want to hide.

So if we inspect your page, the breadcrumb has a div around it with the class breadcrumbs.

So we can add the following to your stylesheet, just like before, with the customizer, Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS.

```
.breadcrumbs {
    display: none; 
}
```

Also, if you are going to make a lot of edits, its better to make a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), then you can override the stylesheet without having to use the admin customizer.

Comment: .title-box is here.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/removing-breadcrumb-and-title-section/

ok. i look into child theme.tq